# Define point or area of a letter to show typographic information

Tags: fonts, typography

I would like to define specific points or areas of characters:

- uppermost / lowermost point
- horizontal line (like in the *m* and *p* in the image where the top horizontals are not the uppermost parts of the letter)
- vertices (like uppermost parts of the *m*)
- closed counters

I will use this information to draw lines or fill in colors to show typographic characteristics:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Which packages do I need and how can I define these points?

Comment: If you mean closed contours, 
[this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405241/27243)
might be relevant.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140580 seems relevant, along with the information you can get from FontForge.